# How to write a SQL query to get multiple values of an ID in one row?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table like below:

```
Col1 col2
1     A
1     B
```

I need to write a DB2 SQL query to get the output as below:

```
Col1 col2 col3
1     A     B
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use `row_number` as follows:

```
Select col1
       max(case when rn = 1 then col2 end) as col2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then col2 end) as col3
From
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partirion by col1 order by col2) as rn
  From t)
Group by col1
```

This method allows to transform more than 2 columns into row. (Just use `rn` in condotional aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id, min(col2), max(col2)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: @SnehaS . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?